# Text overflows on an EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

Sorry if this is another basic question but I'm having a tough time trying to solve this...

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

    <EditTextPreference android:negativeButtonText="Cancel" 
        android:dialogMessage="@string/SettingChangeListOrder"
        android:dialogTitle="Change the order of the list" 
        android:positiveButtonText="Save"
        android:defaultValue="1,2,3,4"      
        android:key="MAINLISTorder" 
        android:title="Change list order"
        android:summary="@string/SCLsummary"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The strings SCLsummary & SettingChangeListOrder are a little bit long. In android 4.1 (emulator) it looks as expected, when the text doesn't fit in a line, it continues in another. But on android 2.3.6, whether the text is 1 character only or 1k characters, it's only displayed in one single line, so it's only possible to read like 3 or 4 words, how can I solve this?? I've tried adding /n multiply times to the strings but it didnt work, I mean, maybe it worked... but the other line is under the EditText so it's worthless

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615650/6391 It looks like you'll have to create your own custom preference.